# Golang create maybe corrupted file

Tags: go

I use the following code which writes YAML content to a file,
we have an old tool in java that do exactly the same and now we are building **new tool** which will do the **same** in Golang.

To create a file with the content I use

```
err := ioutil.WriteFile(tmpDirPath, fileContent, 0777)
```

I don't get any error from this process

I was able to see the **file content and it looks OK** (exactly like the file that was created in the old tool) We have an internal tool which failed to read the file. The error is:

> Error while retrieving archive entry

I check the content (with file diff) and I see that it exactly the same (from the java and Go tools), I'm really Frustrated :( because I don't know how to proceed, maybe the file is corrupted.
I've also tried with `file.Mode = 0644` and it doesn't help.

```
I've Mac and if I can run some checks with command line or other tool to see the diffrent  between the files or maybe between the zip's, (which is created by the old and the new tool) please let me know what to do ...
```

Btw, after I've created the files, I'm, zipping the files and provide it to the internal tool to use it.

If the zip code it needs and can help to identify the problem I can share it also if needed

To create the dir that the file is inside I use

```
func CreateDirIfNotExist(dir string) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(dir); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        err := os.MkdirAll(dir, 0777)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

To zip all content I use after I finish processing:

```
func Zipit(params ...string) error {
    zipfile, err := os.Create(params[1])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(params[0])
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir(); len(params) > 2 {
        baseDir = params[2]
    } else {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(params[0])

    }

    filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, params[0]))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}
```

**update**

I've this folder in my **MAC**

I need to build it on go that I will able to uzip it on mac without errors,
I've tried two tools and I get different errors.

I use the code above to zip the content of it, I know that in the command line there is no error when unzip but our tool cannot read it...
what am I doing wrong with the zip code ? (I need it without the base dir compression )

**some errors is:** with the mac default archive tool and other tool

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**UPDATE 2**

As requested this is **my whole program** which zip the folder successfully after the process done but with the MAC tools it's not possible to unzip them, see the errors above with two diffrent utils, and this dont happen (with mac tools) for other zip files...

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "bufio"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func Zipit(params ...string) error {
    zipfile, err := os.Create(params[1])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(params[0])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir(); len(params) > 2 {
        baseDir = params[2]
    } else {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(params[0])
    }

    filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        fmt.Printf("header: %#v\n", header)

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, params[0]))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}

func CreateDirIfNotExist(dir string) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(dir); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        err := os.MkdirAll(dir, 0777)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    archiveName := "ui5.pre.zip"
    fixedArchiveName := "ui5.zip"

    cmdParams := [][]string{
        {"./ui5", "npm", "install"},
    }

    for _, cp := range cmdParams {
        log.Printf("[INFO] - Starting %s in folder %s...", cp[1:], cp[0])
        cmd := exec.Command(cp[1], cp[2:]...)
        cmd.Dir = cp[0]
        // Wait to finish, get output:

        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic("%s cmd.StdoutPipe() error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)

        }

        // Start command:
        cmd.Start()

        // Stream the execution of the current command
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        oneRune := make([]byte, utf8.UTFMax)
        for {
            count, err := stdout.Read(oneRune)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s", oneRune[:count])
        }
        log.Println()

        // Get execution success or failure:
        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            log.Panic("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)

        }
        log.Println("Finished %s", cp[1:])

    }

    if err := Zipit("ui5", "ui5.pre.zip"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if err := exec.Command("zip", "-F", archiveName, "--out", "./"+fixedArchiveName).Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }


}
```

Comment: Unless you do something crazy, each solution is going to be the same "efficiency". Why not just optimize to make your code simpler?

Comment: @JimB - Thanks, what do you mean by optimize ? I'm open to any suggestion...

Comment: I mean "optimize to make the code simpler". If you can do it in 3 steps, why do it in more with no good reason?

Comment: @JimB - Sorry im not sure that i understand :), what do you mean by 3 steps ?

Comment: The 3 steps you already laid out -- "delete the app1 folder", "create and empty folder", "move the zip file".

Comment: I think what @JimB is saying is that there is no significant difference in efficiency between those two approaches, which I agree with.  So do whatever is easier/faster for you to implement and maintain.  If you mean something different from "efficiency", please clarify your question.

Comment: By 'efficient' I believe you are referring to your code complexity not as it relates to how the underlying os handles the files/folders. Well which is less/cleaner code? I would assume #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the same discussed https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/0iae5Ng-I-0 and depends on ZIP64 format, which used Go archive/go.

An answer recommended using a Go wrapper for Java's ZipInputStream https://github.com/30x/zipper.

**Updated:**
First, call

```
go get github.com/30x/zipper
```

to load zipper package.

Then try to use this version of your Zipit function to check a solution:

```
import "github.com/30x/zipper"
......
func Zipit(params ...string) error {
    return zipper.Archive(params[0], params[1], zipper.Options{
        ExcludeBaseDir: false, // or true 
    })
}
```

Or try to fix archive created your Zipit function (as in the question) to make it ZipInputStream compatible. Call the zipper.Process function next your Zipit version function call in your project:

```
archiveName := "archive.zip" // example code, using yours

err := Zipit(tmpDirPath, archiveName)
if err!=nil {
    return err
}
err := zipper.Process(archiveName, archiveName)
if err!=nil {
    return err
}
```

**Second version** to fix an archive - using zip with an option -F:

```
archiveName := "ui5.pre.zip" 
fixedArchiveName := "ui5.zip" 

if err := Zipit("ui5", archiveName); err != nil { 
    fmt.Println(err) 
} 

if err := exec.Command("zip", "-F", archiveName, "--out", fixedArchiveName).Run(); err != nil { 
    fmt.Println(err) 
}
```

---

**The result** of the chat conversation.
The problem is placed in two parts in your code.

**First part** depends on file info of archive item. Path has to be as a relative, but not absolute. File info header name needs to trim '/' in prefix.

Two piece of code needs to fix.

First:

```
var baseDir string
if info.IsDir(); len(params) > 2 {
    baseDir = params[2]
} else {
    baseDir = filepath.Base(params[0])
}
// add the line:
if len(baseDir)>0 {
    baseDir += "/" // add a suffix to trim it in a file name
}
```

Second:

```
if baseDir != "" {
    header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, baseDir)) // using baseDir to trim but not params[0]
}
```

**Second part** depends on directories added to an archive.

Skip directories at all while building an archive to get the same result as your Java tools.

```
filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // move up this piece of code
    if info.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if baseDir != "" {
        header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, baseDir))
    }

    // simplify code - just define a method 
    //if info.IsDir() {
    //  header.Name += "/"
    //} else {
    header.Method = zip.Deflate
    //}

    writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // too late - directory is already in the archive
    //if info.IsDir() {
    //  return nil
    //}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sound a direction to check becouse the tool who reading the zip is java based tool..., It will be great if you can provide compelite  example with my contect and i'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @shopiaT Try to use source code from an updated part.

Comment: HI Alex, it seems that this is a good direction ,but when I try to use the api you suggest and I try at the process end to unzip the files (from mac)  I got error, do you have an idea ? maybe using other OS ?

Comment: what do you think about this - go get github.com/mholt/archiver/cmd/archiver?

Comment: @shopiaT I tested it on MacOS. Yes, I got an error for unpack, but it is good for your Java tools. The solution is compromise. How often do you unpack the result archive by hand? Does it need in general way?

Comment: @shopiaT Do you test the solution using your Java tools?

Comment: github.com/mholt/archiver is just a wrapper for a standard Go archive/zip, etc. package without fix the ZIP64 format file for a ZipInputStream.

Comment: Ok, I'll now test it with the tool but before I need to remove the parent folder, i.e. when unzip I need to see just the files inside and not the parent folder. i've tried to play with the `ExcludeBaseDir: true` which doesnt help, any idea?

Comment: I recommend you to call zipper.Process after your version Zipit function call against using zipper.Archive with Options. It is more compliance your requirements and archive workflow.

Comment: when I use the process I got error from the tool :`zip: checksum error` , any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165115/discussion-between-shopia-t-and-alexey-p).

Comment: Hi Alexey , are you available

Comment: Yes. Did you try to use zip command to fix golang made an archive?

Comment: Yes but Im getting different errors, do you have mac or windows?

Comment: I have no error on Mac OS when using exec.Command("zip", "-F", archiveName, "--out", fixedArchiveName).Run() without apply zipper package.

Comment: Continue in chat?

Comment: yes, can you re-join ? did you see my update ? did you try to zip the folder I sent https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IWnOKHktbHIUAmEQFMCHdkK3-4ClSkdI

Comment: HI Alex, can you chat ?

Comment: @shopiaT see my third update. It was created as a result of chat conversation.

Comment: HI Alex I'll check it in 20 min, I'm currently on train

Comment: HI, I still getting the same error , did you check the artifacts and it look the same with `diff -y (unzip -l old.zip | psub) (unzip -l new.zip | psub)` ?

Comment: can you share also the whole code that I can test it on my end, just to verify that I dont miss anything...

Comment: Hi Alex, can we chat shortly

Comment: HI alex can you assist?

Comment: See my answer in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's impossible for the files to be identical and the interpreter program to give different results. You're not writing the whole history in your description.

1. How can I check if the file is corrupted ?

The answer is in the internal tool. You should improve its debug message: "Error while retrieving archive entry". What error ? Debug your old tool. And it's suggesting the problem is in the zip file, not the json file.

2. Should I try to use other API to check it? if yes, which ?

Yes, unzip both files by hand and diff the output.

3. Any other direction ?

Read the code for your old java tool.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately Your suggestion is doesn't really help ...see the update with the code I've provided , I've provided 100 bounty for this...Btw, the internal tool is legacy which I cannot change :(